# How to hold stylesheet reference in lotusscript using html tags

Tags: html, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I am building output search result in HTML on my domino web applications. for that I would like to refer style sheet which is part of resources in the database.

I have done following code to refer stylesheet but there seems to be no effect interms of underlying table.

```
Print "<!DOCTYPE html>"
    Print " <html>"
    Print  "<form>"
    Print  " <head><link rel="stylesheet" href='mycss.css'></head>"
    Print  "<Body>"
```

and this is table where referenced the class of stylesheet.

```
Print "<TABLE class ='blueTable' BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0 WIDTH=100% ><TR><TD>"
```

Please help me what is wrong here.

Comment: Have you used the debugging tools in your browser to check whether the css has actually been loaded? My guess is that your URL is wrong. I.e., that 'mycss.css' may need to be '../mycss.css', but without knowing what the URL of the results page looks like I can't be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Richard, below worked

```
    Print  " <head><link rel='stylesheet' href='./mycss.css'></head>"
```

Stylesheet has to be in single comma. (')

Thanks

Comment: Lotus script has three characters that can be used to start and end strings. Double Quotes ("This is a string"), Vertical bar (|The is a string|) and braces ({This is a string}). Generally I use the vertical bar or braves for HTML agents so that I can have the double quotes inside the string (|This is a string with "quoted content."|)